# Creating Do loop that cycles back to earlier values

Tags: functions

I need to create a `Do` loop that distributes letters in a list of lists. I also need to be able to cycle back through to the beginning of the list. For example, I need to change

```
list={{a},{a},{a},{a},{a},{a},{a},{a}}
```

to

> ```
> {{a,b},{a},{a,b},{a},{a,b},{a},{a,b},{a}}.
> ```

But, I need to add the `b` to `list[[5]]`, then `list[[7]]`, then `list[[1]]`, then `list[[3]]`. Is there any way to use a do function to do that or should I find another method?

Comment: `list1 = Insert[list, b, {#, 2} & /@ {1, 3, 5, 7}]` and _"cycle back"_ `Delete[list1, {#, 2} & /@ {1, 3, 5, 7}]`?

Comment: You can use `Mod`. But I'm not convinced that `Do` is the best approach to this anyway.

Answer (score 2):

```
list = {{a}, {a}, {a}, {a}, {a}, {a}, {a}, {a}};
list[[1 ;; -1 ;; 2]] = {a, b};
list
```

> {{a, b}, {a}, {a, b}, {a}, {a, b}, {a}, {a, b}, {a}}

```
list[[1 ;; -1 ;; 2]] = {a};
list
```

> {{a}, {a}, {a}, {a}, {a}, {a}, {a}, {a}}

The catch:

```
b = Range@Length@list[[1 ;; -1 ;; 2]]
```

> {1, 2, 3, 4}

```
list[[1 ;; -1 ;; 2]] = b;
list
```

> {1, {a}, 2, {a}, 3, {a}, 4, {a}}

Comment: could use `list[[;; ;; 2]]` instead of `list[[1;;-1 ;; 2]]`.

Answer (score 1):

```
ClearAll[lst, pos];
lst = Array[{Subscript[a, #]} &, {8}]
(* {{Subscript[a, 1]}, {Subscript[a, 2]}, {Subscript[a, 3]},
    {Subscript[a, 4]}, {Subscript[a, 5]}, {Subscript[a, 6]}, 
    {Subscript[a, 7]}, {Subscript[a, 8]}}*)
pos = RotateRight[Range[1, 8, 2], 2] 
(* {5, 7, 1, 3} *);
Do[AppendTo[lst[[i]], b], {i, pos}];
lst
(* {{Subscript[a, 1], b}, {Subscript[a, 2]}, {Subscript[a, 3], b}, 
    {Subscript[a, 4]},   {Subscript[a, 5], b}, {Subscript[a, 6]}, 
    {Subscript[a, 7], b}, {Subscript[a, 8]}} *)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a bit ambiguous, so I've made the assumption you want to treat the list as circular, and do replacements until you'd pass something already replaced.

```
appendToSublists[list_, toAppend_, start_, step_] := 
 With[{work = ArrayPad[list, {{0, Length@test}, {0, 0}}, "Periodic"]},
  RotateRight[ReplacePart[work, 
     pos_ /; MemberQ[Range[start, 2*Length@list, step], pos] :> 
      Append[work[[pos]], toAppend]][[start ;; start + Length@list - 1]], start - 1]]
```

Arguments are the target list, what to append, start position, and step size.

Some example output (first is your example case ):

```
list = {{a}, {a}, {a}, {a}, {a}, {a}, {a}, {a}}

Column[{
  appendToSublists[list, b, 5, 2],
  appendToSublists[list, b, 3, 2],
  appendToSublists[list, b, 3, 3],
  appendToSublists[list, b, 8, 3]
  }]

(*
{
 {{{a, b}, {a}, {a, b}, {a}, {a, b}, {a}, {a, b}, {a}}},
 {{{a, b}, {a}, {a, b}, {a}, {a, b}, {a}, {a, b}, {a}}},
 {{{a, b}, {a}, {a, b}, {a}, {a}, {a, b}, {a}, {a}}},
 {{{a}, {a}, {a, b}, {a}, {a}, {a, b}, {a}, {a, b}}}
}
*)
```